# Insertion and Searching of a String in a Trie data structure

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, trie

I am currently learning about Trie Data Structure. I am looking for sample implementations in which there's a part the gets me confused.

Here is the sample code I found:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int alpha=26;
struct node{
    node* child[alpha];
   bool end;
   int countchild;
};
node* getnode(){
    node* pnode=new node;
    pnode->end=false;
    pnode->countchild=0;
    for(int i=0;i<alpha;i++){
        pnode->child[i]=NULL;
    }
    return pnode;
}
void insert(node* root,string key){
    node* pcrawl=root;
    int size=key.length();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        int index=key[i]-'a';
        if(!pcrawl->child[index]){
            pcrawl->child[index]=getnode();
        }
        pcrawl->countchild+=1;
        pcrawl=pcrawl->child[index];
        
    }
    pcrawl->end=true;
}
```

Now, on the insert function, what does this line mean:

```
int index=key[i]-'a';
```

I don't know why is it specifically 'a' that needs to be subtracted. I always see that it's the character 'a'. Sorry for sounding kinda dumb on this but I couldn't just understand.

Comment: Check an ASCII character table.

Comment: `key[i]-'a'` turns a value that lies between `'a'` and `'z'` into a value that lies between `0` and `25`, suitable as an index into an array of size 26.

Comment: Where the character value 'a' is 97. Same as:  int index = key[i] - 97

Answer (score 1):

### Why and how does it work?

As you can see, the `node` uses a fixed-size array of pointers:

```
node* child[alpha];
```

where `const int alpha=26;`

This means that at each node, it stores the next node using an index between 0 and 25 in that array.  `key[i]-'a'` computes this index,  keeping in mind that `key[i]` is a `char` i.e. an integral type that stores the numeric value corresponding to the [encoding of the letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

### Weakness of the program

This program assumes that:

- all letters of the string parameter are lowercase letters between `a` and `z`
- lowercase letters are contiguous in the encoding convention (fortunately this is true in all main encodings) and the order of the encoding corresponds to the alphabetical order.

Unfortunately,  this program is UB is there are non-lowercase characters in the string parameter.  A safer approach would be to use

```
int index=tolower(key[i])-'a';  // case insensitive version
```

and to ignore non alphabetic characters:

```
if (index<0 || index>=alpha) 
    continue;
```

Here a [first improvement](https://ideone.com/Yt30Os) (the two remarks above, use of vectors instead of arrays,  and use of member functions instead of free functions.
A next improvement would be to use smart pointers to get rid of manual memory management, an d maybe even maps.

Comment: In what way is `std::vector` an improvement? Wouldn't `std::array` make more sense, since the code always allocates `alpha` elements?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum You are perfectly right: the list of improvements I made, the vector is indeed the less obvious.  Fixed size arrays are perfectly ok provided that `alpha` stays fixed at compile time (no VLA support in C++). As I was refactoring the function I preferred to use vectors and considered it as improvement in view of  multilingual environments, in which the relevant letters for the trie may depend on the locale of the execution environment at run-time.  But I agree that vectors will not bring any benefit if the scope remains pure ascii.

Comment: I'd make the alphabet a template parameter, so the size is fixed per instantiation, but can be flexible for various multilingual environments. I implemented parameter packs for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887433/trie-implementation-with-map/69610280#69610280)

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum THis is an interesting approach.  However isn't this a compile-time solution; if the alphabet would depend on some configuration file or OS parameters at run-time would it work?  By the way, I think that this impressive solution might be out of reach for OP for the time being ;-)

Comment: Changing this to runtime would be almost identical, all it needs ultimately are the mapping arrays. And the helper could take a vector of tuples for example to create them { {A,a}, {B,b} ... }. And yes, something to reach for...

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why is it specifically 'a' that needs to be subtracted

Because everyone who copies this code doesn't know it **either**.

What you got is a trie that works for ASCII characters 'a' to 'z'. Why on Earth would anyone implementing example code add such an unnecessary and confusing restriction is largely beyond my understanding.

The code would be simpler and more understandable without this restriction, and if it were plain C. As it stands, the code is basically "C-with-iostreams". Tries in C++ wouldn't look this way, because C++ is not C. Container in C++ are expected to be iterable, and to reasonably support standard algorithms, etc.

Yes, you can write C++ like it was C. But you'd do that mainly when you don't really understand C++, and at that point it makes much more sense to stick to C and don't pretend otherwise. Writing good C code is a skill in itself. I'd argue that there isn't a simple "transition path" from C to C++: they are different languages, and if you apply C idioms to C++ code, you'll be writing code that's unnecessarily inscrutable.

<sub>This code you found is one more case of blind leading the blind when it comes to search terms that are highly sought after for some coding "challenge" sites :/</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why is it specifically 'a' that needs to be subtracted. I always see that it's the character 'a'.

The problem is mapping 'a' -> 'z' to 0 -> 25 so it can be used as an array index. Trying to map 'a' to 0:

'a'-X=0.

It would seem X equal to 'a' works nicely. This in fact is guarenteed.  Looking at mapping 'b' to 1 is trickier.
For this we need a convient encoding. ASCII works, but is not always the case, so depending on it can lead to undefined behavior. In ASCII, 'a' is 97 and 'b' is 98. That also works nicely, as 'b' - 'a' in ASCII is 1. This will work all the way to 'z' as an effective map from char to index.
So that is why 'a' is subtracted.

The issue is that not all systems use ASCII, so its not a portable solution. This becomes a requirement.

The second problem is one of contract. Is it required that all uses only pass a string containing char in the range: 'a' -> 'z'? If it is required then no checking is needed. Any use outside that is undefined and can do anything. Defensive coding, to enforce only 'a'->'z', would only be needed if a contract can not be established.  This defensive contract is most usuable in internal classes that have no external users.
If this is part of an open API, then guards might be required, but as an out of context snippet. Maybe needed, maybe not. So err on the side of less code.